# API: Update model through an other related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, sql-update

I'm trying make it possible to update a a LineItem trough a CreditNote. It's for an API, so I'm trying to update that trough a JSON.

My relational model is:

```
class TestCreditNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :credit_notes
  has_many :line_items, :class_name => TestLineItem, :foreign_key => :artef_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end

class TestLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :line_items
  attr_accessible :description
  belongs_to  :credit_note, :class_name => TestCreditNote, :foreign_key => :artef_id
end
```

When executing this test:

```
  it "should update the sales line item record" do
    put "api/v1/credit_notes/#{@credit_note.id}", { :test_credit_note => { :line_items => [{ :description => 'PEPITO'}]  }}, http_headers
    data = JSON.parse(response.body, :symbolize_names => true)
    TestCreditNote.find(@sales_credit_note.id).line_item.description.should == 'PEPITO'
  end
```

It fails because of:
     ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
       Can't mass-assign protected attributes: line_items

Answer (score 0):

I've add the attr_accesible :line_items_attributes

```
  class TestCreditNote < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = :credit_notes
    has_many :line_items, :class_name => TestLineItem, :foreign_key => :artef_id
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
    attr_accessible :line_items_attributes
  end
```

And the same in the test

```
it "should update the sales line item record" do
  put "api/v1/credit_notes/#{@credit_note.id}", { :test_credit_note => { :line_items_attributes => [{:id => 1, :description => 'PEPITO'}]  }}, http_headers
  data = JSON.parse(response.body, :symbolize_names => true)
  TestCreditNote.find(@sales_credit_note.id).line_item.description.should == 'PEPITO'
end
```